# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some code here to search the existing name during the keyup() event. It got the correct result. But it shows `Cannot read property "length" of undefined`. Why?

```
function ajax(firstname)
 {
var pathxml;
var answer;
var result;
if(firstname.length== 0)
{
    document.getElementById("hh").innerHTML = "";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  pathxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    pathxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

pathxml.onreadystatechange= function()
{
    if (pathxml.readyState==4 && pathxml.status==200) 
    {
         answer = JSON.parse(pathxml.responseText);
      document.getElementById("hh").innerHTML = "";

    }
    for (var i=0; i<=answer.length; i++)
    {
        result = answer[i].firstname + " " +answer[i].lastname + "\n";
        document.getElementById("hh").innerHTML += result;
    }
}
pathxml.open("GET","books/ax?firstname=" + firstname, true);
pathxml.send();
}
```

controller action:

```
def ax
@books =Book.where("firstname like ?","#{params[:firstname]}%")
render json: @books.as_json
end
```

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="text" name "search" onkeyup="ajax(this.value);">
</form>
<div id ="hh">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It basically means that you're trying to use a property on a variable which value is still not defined, but you might think it is.

- It's possible that you're passing null into `ajax(firstname)`, causing `firstname` to be null or undefined and therefor it contains no property length.
- `answer` is null or undefined if you don't hit the if condition.

Checking if the length of `firstname` is 0 is not enough if it's null or undefined. Make sure that `firstname` is not null or undefined before you begin to check it's `lenght` property and move the `for` loop inside of the if statement to make sure you won't be trying to access the `lenght` property of `answer` even when it's null or undefined.

Providing a line with the error would help to tell which case it is, logging what piece of code is hit would also help you to understand which if statements are fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pathxml.readyState==4 && pathxml.status==200) 
{
     answer = JSON.parse(pathxml.responseText);
  document.getElementById("hh").innerHTML = "";

}
for (var i=0; i<=answer.length; i++)
{
    result = answer[i].firstname + " " +answer[i].lastname + "\n";
    document.getElementById("hh").innerHTML += result;
}
```

I'm fairly sure that `for` loop should be *inside* the `if` block. Just a hunch.

Also, inb4 "why is it all on one line", use this CSS: `#hh {white-space:pre-wrap}`

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
if(firstname.length== 0)
```

in this line you are calling "length" of the "`firstname`" might be null or undefined i.e,. it is not having any value. So you are getting this eror. Make sure "`firsname`" has value. Then check it.

Answer (score 0):

Because it returns sometimes a different state than '4'. Put the 'for' cyscle inside the condition 'if' :)